# Using a hashset to break up a .txt file

Tags: hashmap, hashset

I am trying to write a simple plagiarism program by taking one file and and comparing it to other files by splitting up each file every six words and comparing then to the other files, which is also split up the same way. I was reading up on hashsets and I figured I might try and split them up with hashsets but I have no idea how. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: in what programming language? what is the problem of splitting string to hash sets?

Comment: Its in java and Im just not that familiar with hashsets and how to use them. Does it work like a hashmap?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689517/java-hashset-vs-hashmap

Comment: That helped a lot thank you hopefully this should go pretty quickly now.